# asp.NET controller does not seem to be executing in proper order

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the jQuery File Upload Plugin and posting zip files to my controller. But something is happening with the execution order that I cannot seem to figure out. When I set the debug point at the top it seems to jump all over the place in my controller and because of this, my code does not seem to be working as I would think it should.

Here is my POST:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/FileUpload/Import',
    add: function (e, data) {
        var fileSubmit = data.submit()
            .success(function (result, textStatus, fileSubmit) {
                var name = data.files[0].name;
                fileValidation(name, textStatus);

            })
            .error(function (fileSubmit, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var name = data.files[0].name;
                fileValidation(name, textStatus);
            });           
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function(index, value){
            if (value.name == "") {
                alert("Error uploading: " + value.name + ". " + failStatus);
            }
            else 
            {
                $('#fileSubmit').show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Which seems to be firing off like i think it would. It will POST one file at a time as shown here with Fiddler:

[image]

asp.NET controller does not seem to be executing in proper order and instead bounces all over the place. Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import()
{
    List<ZipContents> fileList = new List<ZipContents>();
    var r = "File successfully uploaded.";

    try
    {         
        if (Session["SESSION_IMPORT_STORAGE"] != null)
        {

            fileList = (List<ZipContents>)Session["SESSION_IMPORT_STORAGE"];
        }

        Stream s = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
        String fn = Request.Files[0].FileName;
        fileList.Add(new ZipContents(s, fn));

        Session["SESSION_IMPORT_STORAGE"] = fileList;

    }
    catch
    {
        r = "An error occurred uploading file(s).";
    }

    return Json(r);
}
```

What I mean by this is that if I set a debug point at:

```
List<ZipContents> fileList = new List<ZipContents>();
```

And then hover over: `String fn = Request.Files[0].FileName;` it says: `"moreXmlFiles.zip"`

Then I hit F11 and it moves to the next line. And again steps into the `try`. and again hits the `if statement`.

If I hit F11 again it goes all the way to my original debug point and when I hover over `String fn = Request.Files[0].FileName;` again it shows the next file name already. But my code didn't even finish  with the first file...

Does anyone know what is going on here?! Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Multiple threads are processing files..

Comment: @stuartd - What would you recommend i do in this situation?

Comment: I would recommend you to just save these files in the HTTP request and use a background thread to zip them later.

Comment: @allentranks - I am not really sure how I would want to proceed with the rest of my code then. I need to store them to session as a list because the user hits a final submit that checks a final list for the files they actually want processed. which is in another Controller.

Comment: Use SQL session state - it will force serialized calls :) Side note: you probably don't want to store files in session state (especially in-memory one)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Thanks for the reply. How would i go about using a SQL session state. I have never had to do this before. And the reason why i am using a session is because i need the files to be stored after the initial import and the refreshing of the page.

Comment: SQL session state is one of  3 modes for ASP.Net session state available with Framework. Search - http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+SQL+session+state will give you plenty good links. Suggestion was more or less joke because even if it will force your code to work correctly it does not mean it is good solution (clearly much more reliable than in-memory state which is lost of recycles and allows access to data for the state from multiple threads at the same time...). Storing file stream in separate DB/file system is likely better approach overall.